# Excel fails to read out variable

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have the following code:

```
Dim FinalAddr As Range
Dim Final As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next


Select Case UCase(Target.Value)


   Case "NEW-BOX"
        Selection.Offset(-1, 2).Select
        FinalAddr = Range(Selection.Address)
        MsgBox FinalAddr ' Debug, nothing comes up however
        Selection.ClearContents
        Selection.Offset(1, -2).Select

   Case "END-BOX"
        Final = FinalAddr.Value
        Application.Speech.Speak (Final)

    End Select
End Sub
```

However, when I scan new box nothing happens, is all of the syntax correct? I get no errors, any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint on `Case "NEW-BOX"`?

Comment: Insert a `Case Else: MsgBox "You provided " & UDase(Target.Value)`before the `End Select` statement to see what is being checked.

Comment: What is it you want to print in the MsgBox?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev I have tried a breakpoint however the code executes fine and just does not set the variable.

Comment: @mattboy I would like it to print the range of the selection, so I can check that the variable is being set, however it does not set at all

Comment: @PeterAlbert I have, and that message box also displays blank after "You Provided ".. strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is  this what you're after?

```
   Case "NEW-BOX"
        Selection.Offset(-1, 2).Select
        MsgBox Selection.Address ' Debug, nothing comes up however
        Selection.ClearContents
        Selection.Offset(1, -2).Select
```

EDIT: If you want to set the FinalAddr to the selection and then test that it works:

```
   Case "NEW-BOX"
        Selection.Offset(-1, 2).Select
        Set FinalAddr = Selection
        MsgBox FinalAddr ' Debug, nothing comes up however
        Selection.ClearContents
        Selection.Offset(1, -2).Select
```

Comment: Sorry no, I am trying to set the FinalAddr variable to the range, and then get the value of that range and pass it to the voice synthesis in the next case

Comment: Then just remove the `.address`

Comment: Right, just remove `.Address` in second example to get the value, see updated post.

Comment: Thank you, this is correct and solved my problem, everything now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value in the cell you should be using  `Finaladdr = Selection.Value`, but if you want the address the selection you should use `= Selection.AddressLocal()`

However if you want to refer to the range youll need to use `Set` and then `.AddressLocal()` when refering to the cells address.